# Displaying navbar on multiple pages using Bootstrap v3.3.5

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating the website that have a navigation bar through all pages based on template called navbar.html and it is loaded by jQuery. All works fine except one issue. The issue is that when I change the screen size on iPad or iPhone menu does not open when hamburger icon is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <div id="navbar"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#navbar").load("navbar.html");
});
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but could  you consider to use something like: `<?php include 'navbar.php';?>` in oder to inject your navbar?

Comment: Please verify, whether you have added an event for the hamburger click event and the proper css.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reaction, I am very glad ... However, I would like to keep it in HTML, so I would better leave the idea that require PHP. I guess that if PHP is used for above issue then all pages .html has to be changed for .php, is that right ...? CSS should not be the issue would say, rather event ...? I did not create any other functionality for it as I expected that Bootstrap would do that if decided for this framework. If I am wrong, please may I ask you for suggestions in regarding to event click here ...?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```css
.navbar-toggle { float: left;margin: 0; height: 50px; width: 50px; background: #444; border-radius: 0;z-index: 1}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar { width: 28px; background: #fff;transition: .5s ease;}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar:nth-child(2){transform: rotate(0)translateY(0)translateX(0);}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar:nth-child(3){opacity:1}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar:nth-child(4){transform:rotate(0)translateY(0)translateX(0);}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-child(2){transform: rotate(-45deg)translateY(5px)translateX(-5px);}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-child(3){opacity: 0}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-child(4){transform:rotate(45deg)translateY(-4px)translateX(-3px);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked for me ... Thank you. Id did not fit the content entirely, but when resized, menu opens after icon clicked ... Very confusing ...Would you also help me to find out solution, how to add image next to Brand text, please  ...?